# save hash in database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to save a hash in my database but this does not work

this is my table in my database

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name",      limit: 255
    t.integer "client_id", limit: 4
    t.integer "event_id",  limit: 4
    t.text    "color",     limit: 65535
  end
```

in my model try with `serialize`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :color, Hash
end
```

in my controller:

```
def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :color, :event_id)
end
```

when I try to save it I get this in my console:

```
 Parameters: {"category"=>{"event_id"=>"2", "name"=>"dwdqwd", "color"=>{"color"=>"#ad1d1d", "opacity"=>1}}}

Unpermitted parameter: color

SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`, `event_id`) VALUES ('dwdqwd', 2)
```

How can I save the hash in my database?

Answer (score 2):

`.permit(:color)` does not work since a hash is not considered a [permitted scalar type](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values).

> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric,
>   TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO,
>   ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.

You can whitelist a hash of nested parameters by passing an array of permitted keys:

```
params.require(:category)
      .permit(:name, :event_id, color: [:color, :opacity])
```

To allow any keys use an empty hash:

```
params.require(:category)
      .permit(:name, :event_id, color: {})
```

See:

- [Rails guides: Nested Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#nested-parameters)